# Get index of current object in array? Pass current object to a function. Angular JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

I am trying to call a function from an object in an array. (The objects of the array are placed on a map.) The function should evaluate what 'status' the object has, and return a url for an icon based on the status. I have to pass the current object to the function.. But how do I do it?

My array of objects:

```
mvc.models = [{
  id: "1",
  icon: evaluateColor(currentObject),
  status: 'green'
},
{
  id: "2",
  icon: evaluateColor(currentObject),
  status: 'red'
}];
```

My function:

```
function evaluateColor(currentObject) {
  if (currentObject.status === 'green') {
    return 'images/green_marker.png'
  }
  else if (currentObject.status === 'yellow') {
    return 'images/yellow_marker.png'
  }
  else {
    return 'images/red_marker.png'
  }
}
```

I have tried to pass the object to the function by passing 'this', but the object logs as undefined. Probably because 'this' refers to the controller and not the object.

```
mvc.models = [{
  id: "1",
  icon: evaluateColor(this),
  status: 'green'
},
{
  id: "2",
  icon: evaluateColor(this),
  status: 'red'
}];
```

And if someone wants to see the html: (the objects are houses that should be shown on an angular google maps)

```
<ui-gmap-markers
        models='mvc.models'
        coords="'coords'"
        icon="'icon'"
        >
</ui-gmap-markers>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: You need to pass the individual item from the array. e.g. mvc.models[index]. Can you please share the code from where you are trying to call evaluateColor function ???

Comment: show us what you have tried in angular

Comment: *"I have tried to pass the object to the function by bassing eg. 'house' and 'this'"* - what house? You need to show us the code.

Comment: Now I have added the code, I don't think that it matters where the array is used though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass whole object to evaluateColor. Modify it to

```
function evaluateColor(status) {
  if (status === 'green') {
    return 'images/green_marker.png'
  }
  else if (status === 'yellow') {
    return 'images/yellow_marker.png'
  }
  else {
    return 'images/red_marker.png'
  }
}
```

and call it with `evaluateColor('green'/'yellow')` , as you anyways have the color available while initializing the object.
this.status will not work as the object declaration is still not complete.

Alternatively, you can call initialize models without icon attribute and call this function:

```
for(var i in models){
   models[i].icon = evaluateColor(models[i].status);
}
```

Hope this solves your query.. :)

Comment: The last thing you suggested works! It is may not be very good to loop through the array if there is a large amount of objects in it.. But for now this works! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy. A slight modification in your code to allow proper scoping will solve it. Check this up;

```js
mvc = {
  models:
    [
      {
       id: "1",
     icon: evaluateColor,
   status: 'green'
      },
      {
       id: "2",
     icon: evaluateColor,
   status: 'red'
      }
    ]
  };

function evaluateColor() {
  if (this.status === 'green') {
    return 'images/green_marker.png';
  }
  else if (this.status === 'yellow') {
    return 'images/yellow_marker.png';
  }
  else {
    return 'images/red_marker.png';
  }
}
console.log(mvc.models[0].icon());
```

However i don't like that nested ifs and thens. A more proper approach would be like

```js
mvc = {
  models:
    [
      {
       id: "1",
     icon: evaluateColor,
   status: 'green'
      },
      {
       id: "2",
     icon: evaluateColor,
   status: 'red'
      },
      {
       id: "3",
     icon: evaluateColor,
   status: 'yellow'
      }
    ]
  };

function evaluateColor() {
var lut = { green : 'images/green_marker.png',
           yellow : 'images/yellow_marker.png'};
return lut[this.status] || 'images/red_marker.png';
}

console.log(mvc.models[0].icon());
console.log(mvc.models[1].icon());
console.log(mvc.models[2].icon());
```

Well if you don't want icon to be a function to run each time you need to get the icon then you may simply define an init property to initialize the objects properly... Ok lets do it.

```js
mvc = {
  models:
    [
      {
       id: "1",
     icon: "",
   status: 'green',
     init: getIcon
      },
      {
       id: "2",
     icon: "",
   status: 'red',
     init: getIcon
      },
      {
       id: "3",
     icon: "",
   status: 'yellow',
     init: getIcon
      }
    ]
  };

function evaluateColor() {
var lut = { green : 'images/green_marker.png',
           yellow : 'images/yellow_marker.png'};
return lut[this.status] || 'images/red_marker.png';
}

function getIcon(){
  this.icon = evaluateColor.call(this);
}
mvc.models.forEach(e => e.init())
console.log(JSON.stringify(mvc,null,2));
```

Answer (score 0):

try another pattern

```
mvc.models.push({ id : '1' , status : 'green'});
mvc.models.push({ id : '2' , status : 'red'});

$.each(mvc.models , function(idx, item){ item.color = eluateColor(item.status)});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create `icons` [as getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) instead field, like this

```
mvc.models = [{
  id: "1",
  get icon(){ return evaluateColor(this);},
  status: 'green'
},
{
  id: "2",
  get icon(){ return evaluateColor(this);},
  status: 'red'
}];
```